# Call class method while debugging in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I call a method while my app is being run under the debugger?

I have tried entering an expression in the *watch* pane that contains a call, but it did not work.

My app is running and if possible I don't want to set a breakpoint before calling the method because I'm trying to interrogate some things when the app is idle.  I would like to run the call in the UI thread.  I can make any changes necessary to the code to accomodate this.

Comment: Last time I checked, the watch pane worked fine. It just does not catch the breakpoints that are set there

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't get anything to show up in the watch pane...

Comment: @cricket_007 In fact, if I type "MainActivity." it won't even auto-complete any of the fields in my class, static or otherwise.

Comment: Hmm. It should, for public static at least.. But can you type out the full value?

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried typing out the whole "com.blah.app.MainActivity" style name, if that's what you mean.

Comment: No, just evaluate `MainActivity.SOME_CONSTANT`

Comment: did you try calling method in evaluate expression?